# Not able to access HBase web UI

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am following the [quick start](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart) doc of HBase.

However, I cannot access HBase web UI.

I tried with these addresses:

- http://127.0.0.1:16010/
- http://localhost:16010/
- http://localhost:60010/

I tried different ports because the [documentation](https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.3/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/reference_chap2_4.html) says to use 60010, but the quickstart says 16010.

None of these works.

Here is my hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hduser/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/hduser/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
      Controls whether HBase will check for stream capabilities (hflush/hsync).

      Disable this if you intend to run on LocalFileSystem, denoted by a rootdir
      with the 'file://' scheme, but be mindful of the NOTE below.

      WARNING: Setting this to false blinds you to potential data loss and
      inconsistent system state in the event of process and/or node failures. If
      HBase is complaining of an inability to use hsync or hflush it's most
      likely not a false positive.
    </description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Note: Accessing the shell works well:

```
./hbase shell
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hbase-1.4.12/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
HBase Shell
Use "help" to get list of supported commands.
Use "exit" to quit this interactive shell.
Version 1.4.12, r6ae4a77408ad35d6a7a4e5cebfd401fc4b72b5ec, Sun Nov 24 13:25:41 CST 2019

hbase(main):001:0>
```

Why can't I access the web UI ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 8):

HBase in standalone mode will just choose some random ports to listen on.

Go to 'logs' directory and do

```
grep 'Jetty' *
```

That'll show you the ports HBase has chosen to run its webservers on.

Comment: This is the correct approach outside of binding hbase to you own port of which I haven't figured out yet. The port is in the logs folder. In fact, search for "Jetty bound to port' and use last one. A few hours wasted for me.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, would have wasted a lot of time otherwise.